# .sample on an array is always false in irb

Tags: ruby, arrays, random, false-positive

I am testing in irb and everytime I require my file is is always returning false.

```
class Weather
def stormy
[false, true].sample
end
end
```

it seems to return false know matter what is in the array?
I am unsure if it is my code or the way I am requiring file in irb.
can anyone help 
Thank you

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using, because this won't even run in 2.0 or 2.2 on my machine.  It gives an `undefined method 'random'` error.

Comment: The question mentions "require my file", but there is no require being shown here.  I'd like to see the calling code as well, including any require statements.

Comment: The above code is in a Ruby file weather.rb.  I open irb in terminal. type require_relative 'lib/weather.rb'  and the result I get is true, then every other time I require it is false. I need it to be random. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pick randomly from an `Array` use [sample](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-sample):

```
def stormy
  [ false, true ].sample
end
```

Comment: thanks but seems to return false know matter what is in the array.

Comment: that should not happen. How are you calling it?

Comment: in irb I am requiring the file the code is in 
    require_relative 'lib/weather.rb'

Comment: ok do this. Open irb - define this function - call it. You can see that it works perfectly. I think something else is wrong with other code. My guess - the way you are calling it.

Comment: thank you. can you clarify defining the function (sorry I noob).  do you mean def storm = true ?

Answer (score 1):

The return value of `require` (or `require_relative`) indicates whether the file was loaded successfully or was already loaded. It has nothing to do with any methods that may be defined inside the file.

Once the file defining it has been loaded, to call your method (as currently defined) you would do

```
Weather.new.stormy
```

Comment: Thank you! This has been helpful. As I am so fresh to ruby driving irb is all a little confusing thank you for your answer